# Can I make a if-else statement based on a array?

Tags: php, arrays, function, modularity

Here is my current code:

```
if ( by == 'id') {
    handlePromises(identifier_websites)

} else if ( by == 'name'){
    handlePromises(names_websites)

} else if ( by == 'email' ) {
    handlePromises(email_websites)

} else if ( by == 'phone' ) {
    handlePromises(phone_websites)
}
```

Now I want to make it a little bit more modular *(functional)*. I mean, I want to make the whole code above based on an array like this:

```
$parts = ['id', 'name', 'email', 'phone'];
```

So if I add one item to that array, then *automatically* a `else if` block should be added to the code based on that item .

Is doing that possible?

Comment: Why can't you use switch case instead?

Comment: What is your goal? You want to return handlePromises(identifier_websites) when you do $parts = ['id'] ? Or you have some some code that is reading another code that will generate another code?

Comment: @zwitterion Latter

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if I get you but here's how you can automate the above slightly.

```
$parts = [ 
    'id' => identifier_websites, 
    'name' => names_websites, 
    'email' => emails_websites, 
    'phone' => phone_websites
];

foreach ($parts as $cond => $params) {
     if (by == $cond) { 
        handlePromises($params); 
        break; 
     }
}
```

Comment: What's `<something>` ? Has something between `<>` any specific meaning?

Comment: @MartinAJ Not really. I wasn't sure whether your actual parameters were just an example or if you actually defined a constant for each case (not a good idea by the way if you want to be more flexible). Should match what you had now.

Comment: missing some $s in the values up there for syntax compliance.

Comment: @Calimero it's based on the question. I think OP has `by`, and `*_websites` defined as constants.